How to use Dynamic Subdomains in NextJS 14 with Clerk Auth
I have a NextJS 14 (app router) application with Clerk auth, but I want to add dynamic subdomains so each business will have a subdomain (e.g. thomas-bistro.mysite.app). Due to Clerk middleware this has proved tricky because I have tried to put middleware to handle this but none of it works. This is my current middleware.ts at the route of my directory:
import { clerkMiddleware } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";

export default clerkMiddleware();

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    // Skip Next.js internals and all static files, unless found in search params
    '/((?!_next|[^?]*\\.(?:html?|css|js(?!on)|jpe?g|webp|png|gif|svg|ttf|woff2?|ico|csv|docx?|xlsx?|zip|webmanifest)).*)',
    // Always run for API routes
    '/(api|trpc)(.*)',
  ],
};

I ideally want someone to be able to go to their subdomain and it act like a normal dynamic route.
I have tried to pickup subdomains within the middleware and then redirect, but I get errors due to either ClerkMiddleware not being exported properly or not having a middleware export, I'm not sure how to do both.
Any help would be much appreciated :)
